# Spring security does not intercept login call

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to set up spring security, I have a controller which forwards to a login page after valdiation failure. But my interecept does not seem to pick it up...

Contoller fragment:

```
if (validation not successful) {
   return "login";
}
```

In my xml I have:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="ROLE_USER" />
```

but this fails, I get the following error:

> The requested resource (/myapp/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp) is not available.

How can I get it to interecept the login forward?

Comment: The error looks like you are returning a view name "login" which doesn't exist (i.e. there is no corresponding JSP). That doesn't really have anything to do with Spring Security. It's entirely within your controller configuration and happens after the Spring Security filter chain has been invoked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If user is not logged yet, it means he doesn't have `ROLE_USER`, so Spring Security won't allow to access `/login`.

Add [`use-expressions="true"` to `<http>` element](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#el-access) and change intercept line to this:

```
<http use-expressions="true">
  <!-- ... -->
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="permitAll" />
```

Plus, make sure that login.jsp is under `/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp`.

**EDIT** after comment:

Seem that you have no Spring Security config at all, so begin with this:

```
<http auto-config='true' use-expressions="true">
  <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="permitAll"/>
  <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
  <!-- use login-page='/login' assuming you've got 
       Spring MVC configured to redirect to login.jsp -->
  <form-login login-page='/login'/>
</http>
```

or, if you're using Spring Security 3.1:

```
<http pattern="/login" security="none" />
<http auto-config='true'>
  <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
  <!-- use login-page='/login' assuming you've got 
       Spring MVC configured to redirect to login.jsp -->
  <form-login login-page='/login'/>
</http>
```

Create `/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp` file with example content:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Login</h3>

    <c:if test="${not empty error}">
        <div class="errorblock">
            Your login attempt was not successful, try again.<br /> Caused :
            ${sessionScope["SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"].message}
        </div>
    </c:if>

    <form name='f' action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />"
        method='POST'>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User:</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='j_username' value=''>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type='password' name='j_password' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit"
                    value="submit" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And what's more, please read about Spring Security, because these are really basics of this framework.

Comment: I understand what your saying, however.. i dont have a login jsp, what i wanted was to intercetp the jsp request to spring security login... and then forward on to a welcome page..

Comment: I see.. So the problem is you're a beginner in Spring Security. Please read [reference manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html) and some tutorials, for example [this one](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-example/), to understand the concept.

Comment: Hi,I did read your edit and i followed the example by mkyong, but i had an issue with the redirecting.. once i re-directed it started working. Thanks,